# How can I set up a cookie-free domain without wordpress?

Tags: cookies, static, hosting, web-hosting, browser-cache

I'm trying to set up a cookie-free domain so that my website can achieve better performance and scores from YSlow by serving most static content from a cookie-free domain. However, I'm not sure hot go about this because most tutorials are for WordPress websites, whereas I run my website via a static framework (Hugo) and host it on Google Cloud Firebase. Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.